# Android PagerView with cursorAdaptor

Tags: android

i was following this tutorial

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/

and it is great i am trying to convert my old list view code with simpleCursorView to PagerView the problem is PagerAdapter does not use Cursors

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to do, but I think you need to write your own PagerAdapter, where you must process your Cursor's data.

I mean get data from Cursor and then make them applicable to PagerAdapter.

In tutorial, PagerAdapter displays some layouts. Try to bind your Cursor's data with layouts.